# Can't utilize static files w/ node.js and express

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I'm trying to use node.js and express to create a chat client, but as soon as I try to use external CSS or JS files, I run into GET errors.

Currently I have index.js as:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});


io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

And in my index.html I use:

`<script src="/dropdown.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style1.css">`

to link the files in the HTML.

My code structure is

```
index.js
index.html
public
    style1.css
    dropdown.js
```

I've looked at a bunch of other solutions on stackoverflow and none of them worked. I've tried various combinations of using express.static/app.static and various combinations of linking CSS/JS files in the html file. All of them result in GET errors.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Try this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(process.cwd(), '/public')));
```

Comment: The errors went away, but the CSS is still not applied.

Comment: Actually I have solved it. When running node it created another copy of my css files and js files in the root directory, and I was editing those instead of the ones in public.

Answer (score 0):

Created project with exactly same code and file structure like yours, and it worked. Make sure you have written all file names correctly and all that "obvious" stuff. And if that doesn't help can you provide some error messages?

Comment: For some reason I no longer have errors even without the change above, but the CSS is still not applied.

I copied the CSS code and put it in the HTML file and it worked so its something to do with the middleware